# splitting a string

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [splitting a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996921/splitting-a-string)

i have a string which looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/m5508ff19

i need to get each of the numbers and put them in an array in this order: 0, 50, 100, 100, 200, 400, 218, 9.8, ???, 6.65, 6.31 etc...

i have the following code but for some reason it only does the first column, it only gives me 0, 50, 100, 100, 200, 400, 218, 9.8, ???

```
Dim list_numbers As New List(Of String)

Dim fields() As String
fields = calculationText.Split(Environment.NewLine)


For Each CurrLine As String In fields
    list_numbers.Add(CurrLine.Split(Char.Parse("    "))(0))
Next
```

i need help to get every number in an array in the above order

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996921/splitting-a-string - you should stick with that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you already [ask this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996921/splitting-a-string)?  Did the answers provided there not help you?

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a (0) at the end of the second Split() function; this will only grab the first element.

(Disclaimer - I don't know VB.Net, but this is my best guess based on my C# experience.)

Comment: adam, then what do you recommend i put instead of the 0